# How to change image for UIButton using switch statement?

Tags: ios, uibutton, nsarray, switch-statement

I was able to add a "setbackgroundimage" to my UIButton in my array. Now all buttons have the same image. How do I create a switch statement to be able to set a different image for each initwithobjects @"" in my NSarray?

Below is the code I'm using:

```
 menuItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"", nil];
    for (int b=0;b<[menuItems count];b++) {

        UIButton *mybutton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3.0f, originofButtons, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
        //mybutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [mybutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menubutton.png"]
         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mybutton setTag:b];
        [mybutton setTitle:[menuItems objectAtIndex:b] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mybutton setSelected:false];
        [mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonpress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [m_scrollview addSubview:mybutton];

        originofButtons += (buttonHeight + buttonseparator); 
        }
```

Comment: `[mybutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_SELECTED_IMG.png"]
         forState:UIControlStateSelected];`

Comment: Use `switch(b){}` and set image for each case. What's the issue there ?

Comment: hey @WorldOfWarcraft. i already have that line. i already set the image. but i get the same one on all buttons. i would like to know how i can give the other buttons in the same array a different image each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the image for selected:

```
[mybutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_SELECTED_IMG.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Whereas you want to set different each, you can link `tag` .

```
switch (myButton.tag) {
        case 0:
            [mybutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_SELECTED_IMG.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            break;
        case 1:
            [mybutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_SELECTED_IMG.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            break;
    }
```

Comment: You are the man! that worked. THANK YOU SO MUCH! on the if statement does it matter if my state is selected as?

Comment: You should if-else statements since the tag can only be one value.

Comment: Instead of using if...else conditions, it'll be better to use `switch()` statement, since the tag is an integer value

Comment: @Miguel Actually, you can set the controlState whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

This can be help you for your scenario. 
You can add your button image name in NSArray and then set image for each case using the below code snippet:

```
NSArray*  menuItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"FirstScreen",@"SecondScreen",@"ThridScreen", nil];

for (int b=0;b<[menuItems count];b++) {

    UIButton *mybutton = [[UIButton alloc]init ];//WithFrame:CGRectMake(3.0f, originofButtons, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
    [mybutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[menuItems[b] stringByAppendingString:@".png"]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

i am hoping this will be helpful to you according to your requirements.....

```
menuItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"", nil];
for (int b=0;b<[menuItems count];b++) {

    UIButton *mybutton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3.0f, originofButtons, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
    //mybutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [mybutton setBackgroundImage:[self getImageFromIndex:b %4]
     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mybutton setTag:b];
    [mybutton setTitle:[menuItems objectAtIndex:b] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mybutton setSelected:false];
    [mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonpress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [m_scrollview addSubview:mybutton];

    originofButtons += (buttonHeight + buttonseparator);



    }


-(UIImage *) getImageFromIndex:(short) index
{
switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"card_01.png"];
        break;
    case 1:
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"card_02.png"];
        break;
    case 2:
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"card_03.png"];
        break;
    case 3:
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"card_04.png"];
        break;

    default:
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"card_01.png"];
        break;
}
return nil;
}
```